# Upgrade PHP 5.3.3 to PHP 5.5.38 PEAR encode issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pear

I'm trying to upgrade legacy system to PHP 5.5.38 from PHP 5.3.3. I read data from db and write to file and process the file. When using PHP 5.3.3 (PHP ini default charset latin or utf8), the encoding chars(non-english chars) works fine but when using PHP 5.5.38, the encoding chars does not work well.

I changed RDS db configuration params character-set-server = latin1 in staging server, the encoding works fine.

Production RDS MYSQL DB configuration

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                           |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                            |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                            |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                          |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                            |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                            |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                            |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/oscar-5.6.mysql_aurora.1.19.2.0.157.0/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but contents in table is using latin chars. When I view the text in mysql client I see this

à¸šà¸£à¸´à¸à¸²à¸£ Model clip à¸«à¸™à¹‰à¸²à¹ƒà¸«à¸¡à¹ˆà¹€à¸”à¹‡à¸”à¹† à¸„à¸´à¸”à¹€à¸‡à¸´à¸™ 5à¸š. à¸”à¸¹

PHP 5.3.3 using PEAR version: 1.9.4

PHP 5.5.38 using PEAR version: 1.10.12

I don't understand what causes this issue? How it works in PHP 5.3.3 but not in PHP 5.5.38 (not using htmlspecialchars) after reading the data from DB, just write it to file.

I checked PEAR change log but I couldn't find anything related to charset.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found something 

in php 5.3.3, when I run this query
$this->db->query("select charset('')");

it returns array(1) {
  ["charset('')"]=>
  string(6) "latin1"
}

but in php 5.5.38
array(1) {
  ["charset('')"]=>
  string(4) "utf8"
}

not sure, why?

I use this option to update the charset using PEAR query
$this->db->query("set names latin1");

Comment: Is part of that Thai for `หน้าให`?  See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored